# Need help to avoid `eval´ when capturing output of executed commands in bash

Tags: bash, logging, eval

There are a lot of warnings regarding the use of eval and most people agree that it can be avoided. However, I've tried a lot and in the end, I get a lot of errors unless I use eval.

Basically, I want to capture the output of a command, both for stdout and stderr:

```
run() {
...
    result=$(eval "$*" 2> "tee" -a "$_logfile" >&2)
...
}
```

BTW, I am using "$*" instead of "$@" to avoid shellcheck SC2294 (warning): eval negates the benefit of arrays, and I also quoted tee to avoid SC2238 (warning): Redirecting to/from command name instead of file.

The command that I tried is this:

```
run "yq --input-format xml --output-format props <\"$xmlfile\""
```

Assuming I am not the first one who wants to execute commands and capture the output, are there better ways to do this?

Comment: Not everyone has or uses (or even can install) `yq` - more people will be able to help you if you modify your example to use a mandatory POSIX command like `sed` or `awk` that everyone has so everyone can understand your command and copy/paste it to test with? Also add sample input and expected output.

Comment: Also [Why avoid `eval` and what to use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead)

Comment: @Ed Morton: yq was just an example. The whole point of such a generic run function is to execute *arbitrary* commands. Fill in what you like.

Comment: @pjh: Yes, it does. Second answer: "Use eval"

Comment: @Paul Hodges: I came here to learn what to do instead. The task has been clearly described: Run arbitrary commands and capture the output. "Don't try this" doesn't help.

Comment: If the positional parameters contain a command and arguments that you want to execute, then just do this: `"$@"`.  That expands the parameters into fields and then runs the resulting command.  For instance try this experiment: `set -- ls -l`, and then `"$@"`. It will run `ls -l`.

Comment: @Kaz: That was the very first thing I tried. It does not work. Please try yourself but this time actually a) use a function, and b) pass the argument as "ls -l" (including the quotes). It will complain command not found.

Comment: Several links to other ways to do it, or discussions of how to do it better, have been posted. If they aren't enough, repost the question with better clarity. As stated, you are asking for a function to *do anything*, which is pointless. Clarify what it is you want and we can help you get it, or explain why you can't. Also, remember that `run ls > log`  works **without** passing the redirection to the function...

Comment: Indeed a quoted `ls -l` or any other command is shell syntax. The only way to execute shell syntax is *eval*. Only *eval* will work if you call `func 'for each x in *; do echo $x; done'` such that you want that loop executed by `func`.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do this. Among many other issues listed in [BashFAQ 50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050),

> It's worth noting that you cannot put anything other than a list of arguments into an array variable when using the `"${array[@]}"` technique to evaluate a command. Pipelines, **redirection**, assignments, and any other shell keywords or syntax *will not be evaluated correctly.*

`run()` is generally a bad idea. Don't overdo the abstraction.
Again, from BashFAQ 50 -

> Here's yet another thing that won't work:

```
# BROKEN code.  Do not use!
runcmd() { if ((debug)); then echo "$@"; fi; "$@"; }
```

You could `runcmd ls` or even `runcmd ls foo`, but `runcmd "ls foo"` fails because there's no command named "ls foo", and `runcmd "ls" "foo" ">" "bar"` will just tell you `ls: cannot access '>': No such file or directory` (you hope).

You say

> I am using `"$*"` instead of `"$@"` to avoid shellcheck `SC2294 (warning): eval negates the benefit of arrays`

While this might make shellcheck shut up about that particular warning, it isn't *fixing* it.

> I also quoted tee to avoid `SC2238 (warning): Redirecting to/from command name instead of file.`

Same here. You're just managing to sneak the logic errors past the error checking. You've likely made an empty local file named `tee`, unless there were actual errors - then that's where they went.

```
$: echo foo 2> tee -a bar
foo -a bar

$: ls -l tee
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul 197611 0 Dec 14 05:14 tee
```

This is functionally the same as:

```
$: echo foo -a bar 2> tee
foo -a bar
```

You can put the redirection anywhere.

```
$: echo one > one

$: echo > two two

$: > three echo three

$ grep . one two three
one:one
two:two
three:three
```

So please don't just do random things to make errors stop reporting - you need to actually fix the problems.

Look at some examples:

```
$: run() { "$@"; }

$: run ls one
one

$: run "ls one" # passed as a SINGLE STRING
bash: ls one: command not found

$: run ls * # expanded to individual filenames before passed to the function
one  three  two

$: run ls "*" # not allowed to expand, function looking for files named "*"
ls: cannot access '*': No such file or directory

$: run ls > 4
$: run ls *
4  one  three  two

$: run "ls * > 4"
bash: ls * > 4: command not found

$: run "ls" "*" ">" "4"
ls: cannot access '*': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '>': No such file or directory
 4
```

You can do redirection of the I/O to/from the function itself, but you cannot pass redirection indicators in as arguments, it doesn't work (which is why you can to use `eval`.)

When you execute

> `run "yq --input-format xml --output-format props <\"$xmlfile\""`

it is first expanding `$xmlfile` (let's call it `file.xml`) then passing the single string `"yq --input-format xml --output-format props <"file.xml"` as the only argument to `run`, which is a mess you are hacking through by using `eval`. Clean up the mess and the `eval` becomes less necessary.

Try it this way:

```
format_yaml_to_result() { 
  declare -g result="$(yq 2>&1 <"$1" --input-format xml --output-format props)"
}
format_yaml_to_result "$xmlfile" # $result now set, including any error output
```

Just remember that this is a GLOBAL variable your function is loading, without regard for what else might have been there.

*Don't* try to make one function that runs any command.

I assume you have other stuff in the function where you put ellipses (`...`), and you tagged the OP with `logging` so I suspect this may be a bit of an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). If that's relevant you should show what that stuff is so we can address it.

Comment: Thank you, Paul. Your first quote answers my question. Such that eval is necessary and cannot be avoided in such a run function.

If you change your minimalistic run() { "$@"; } function to run() { result=$(eval "$*"); head <<<$result; }, you will see that all the examples you came up with work as intended, even the redirection--the file 4 will be created and the content will be the output of ls.

The two main intentions behind such a run function have been clearly mentioned: 
1) Run arbitrary commands. 
2) Capture both the standard and error output.

None of these have been addressed.

Comment: You ENTIRELY missed the point, lol... Did you read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 ? *Please* do. Yes, you can totally get the result you want by doing that, but it is not safe in several cases. You could also just use `eval "$1"` and always put everything in a single string, which you were doing anyway - that isn't the answer either. Please be careful - your example is doing exactly the kind of things that are will cause problems later. Post the question again with more detail and less `...` so we can help more!